# GlassFish as windows service

Tags: windows-services, glassfish-3

I am using GlassFish 3.1.2. I want to create a service of GlassFish so that each the system start it will automatically start the GlassFish domain.

In default domain domain1, there is a cluster cluster1 having two instances instance1 and instance2.

But when I use the command...

```
asadmin>domain1Service.exe start
```

It starts the domain, but clusters are not started. So How can I make a service which can start clusters ??

Do I have to create separate service for each instance within a cluster ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create service over cluster instance in GlassFish.

For that we have to create separate service for each instance.
This command is used to create service for each an instance..

```
asadmin>>create-service --nodedir <<node-dir location>>  <<node-name>>
```

Thanks,
Gunjan.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running this on a windows machine, so I would write a batch script (.bat) that executes the appropriate asadmin commands.

```
asadmin start-domain --user admin --passwordfile adminpassword.txt domain1

asadmin start-cluster --user admin --passwordfile adminpassword.txt cluster1
```

Than I would setup the service to point at the batch file.

Comment: HI,
 It seems that you are diverting from the mail question.We can create service over cluster instance in GlassFish. For that we have to create separate service for each instance.This command is useful asadmin>>create-service --node <<node-name>>