# GlassFish server installation executable does not open

Tags: java, glassfish, installation, oracle-adf

I am trying to install GLassfish server using execuatable **glassfish-3.1.2.2-windows.exe**
When i try to open the executable,  after the message **Launching Java 2(TM) Runtime Environment** nothing happens.

I already have Java installed.. if i am correct i tried getting the version from cmd prompt.. it has given me the version

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Now m not sure if the problem lies with environment variable.. but i have tried setting up that too.. but still the same issue.
Seems like m missing something..
Please help...

Comment: Is there a installation guide where it says you need to have JAVA_HOME as a env variable and also in the PATH? And does glassfish need a JDK or a JRE? Any installation logs anywhere? I hate to say it but RTFM - https://glassfish.java.net/docs/3.1.2/installation-guide.pdf and it does talk about a JDK.

Comment: Yes, the installation guide says i will have to set up JAVA_HOME as a env variable. I have Android ADT installed.. and had installed JDK that time.. so have not installed it again.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is an issue with the installer. You can specify your Java installation by passing it with a parameter like this:

```
*GLASSFISH_INSTALLER_NAME* -j  *YOUR_JAVA_INSTALLATION_PATH_TO_JDK*
```

Example:

```
ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"
```

Simply go to the location of the installer on command prompt and type above.

This method worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is an issue with the installer which seems to look for a Java 1.6 installation.

You can specify your Java installation by passing it with a parameter like this:

```
glassfish-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j <YOUR_JAVA_INSTALLATION>
```

Example:

```
glassfish-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
```

If even this doesn't work you can get the ZIP version of GlassFish and extract it in the desired folder.

**See also:**

- [GlassFish as windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819605/glassfish-as-windows-service)
- [Error creating glassfish as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338580/error-creating-glassfish-as-a-service)

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I actually tried this but here i am getting an error that **-j is not a valid argument.** Now i feel like i have gone wrong with environment varaible. Can you please guide me on this..

Answer (score 0):

I could not get a solution to this issue, but used an alternative, i.e downloaded the glassfish server zip file.. extracted it.. and then tried running the application server. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with the path of the command. There are no spaces allowed in the path. You must use the double quotes like:

```
glassfish-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
```